# when active will change background

Tags: html, css

I'm playing with 3 images. and it's making me dizzy. What I want is when a tab is active it will change the background-image.

I have this code right now in my html:

```
div id="promo-nav-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li id="active">
            <a href="#" class="promo-call"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="promo-text"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#promo-nav-wrapper {
background: url("http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/580/menubackground.png/");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 100%;
height: 82px;
}
#promo-nav-wrapper ul {
text-align: center; 
}
#promo-nav-wrapper ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#promo-nav-wrapper ul li a {
height:53px;
width:41px;
display:block;
text-decoration: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-shadow: none;
}
a.promo-call{
background-image:url("http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/861/callicon2.png/");
z-index: 3;
margin-right: 10px;
}
a.promo-text {
background-image:url("http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/807/texticon2.png/");
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
/*this don't work*/
#promo-nav-wrapper li#active a { 
  background-image: url('http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/selectediconbackground.png/') no-repeat!important;
  height: 76px;
  width: 64px;
  /*background: blue;*/
}​
```

My problem is I can't snip the image when an li is active, it doesn't show the background. T_T. Say like this

```
#active a{ background-image: url('selected_icon_background.png');
....

}
```

Comment: That `#active a{ background-image: url('selected_icon_background.png');` isn't in your actual code, it's just an example, right? Just wondering because all of the other ones have `../images/` in front of the filename.

Comment: It does work, look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fBwEJ/. I've used color as a substitute for images.

Comment: can you push your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ for better understanding

Comment: sorry, if it took me a while. I've put my code in jsfiddle.net. Please view: http://jsfiddle.net/si_dean_ako/kyYWU/

Comment: @Rick yup, its just an example. uploaded the necessary image in imageshack. you can view it now in http://jsfiddle.net/si_dean_ako/kyYWU

Comment: @Wondering Coder - check my answer, if a lagging some where please let me know so i can make changes as per requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Acc to what i am understanding after reading the problem -

First of all in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/si_dean_ako/kyYWU/  images are not loading and secondly the css rule is wrong on `#promo-nav-wrapper li#active a`

Try to remove

```
#promo-nav-wrapper li#active a {
  background-image: url('http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/selectediconbackground.png/') no-repeat!important;
  height: 76px;
  width: 64px;
  /*background: blue;*/
}
```

and add like this

```
#promo-nav-wrapper li#active {
  background: url('http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/selectediconbackground.png/') no-repeat!important;
  height: 76px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

When we want to write multiple value (shorthand properties) at that time we have to use `background` property of css and in above fiddle `background-image` is used and on that the `url('image path'), no-repeat, !important;` is applied. And background-image always take the path of the image.

So it better to use like that `background: url('http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/selectediconbackground.png/') no-repeat!important;`

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyYWU/2/ in this fiddle active image is showing behind the `<a href="#" class="promo-call"></a>`.

See the output generated on my local machine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#promo-nav-wrapper #active a { background-image: url('selected_icon_background.png');
....

}
```

at the end of your stylesheet

Comment: Precautionary, but not necessary looking at OP's code. No other CSS property is conflicting so `#promo-nav-wrapper` can be omitted